# How to Get Rid of Line Connecting Points in Google Charts Scatter Plot

Tags: charts, google-visualization, scatter-plot

I've created a Google Charts Scatter plot, but even though I don't specify any lines, the chart draws a line between my points (seen in the picture below as a faint blue line).

[image]

I've tried setting trendline to 0, but it doesn't do anything. How can I make this line go away?

```
function drawScatterPlot (table_arguments={}) {
              
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('number', table_arguments["xtitle"]);
    data.addColumn('number', table_arguments["ytitle"]); // Required to be a number
    
    data.addRows(table_arguments["data"]);
    
    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: table_arguments["title"],
            subtitle: table_arguments["subtitle"]
        },
        hAxis: {title: table_arguments["xtitle"]},
        vAxis: {title: table_arguments["ytitle"]},
        legend: {position: 'none'},
        trendlines: {  0: { opacity: 0 }}
    };
    
    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('scatterchart_material'));

    // DRAW CHART
  
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: you could try option --> `lineWidth: 0` -- have you included all of the options? also, could you please share a sample of the data?

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood that option -- I thought lineWidth controlled the width of the grid lines and trendline controlled the line connecting the points. Do you want to post your solution as the Answer so I can give it credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the line width to zero using the following config option...

```
lineWidth: 0
```

> `lineWidth` - Data line width in pixels. Use zero to hide all lines and show only the points.